# Foundation 5 orbit bullets

Tags: zurb-foundation, orbit

I would like to move bullet navigation on the slider,so it would be somewhere in the middle. 
But when i do this and click on the other slide the bullets disappear.
 Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code, please. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

You need to override some of the orbit bullets CSS rules, like:

```
.orbit-bullets {
  position: absolute; // instaed of relative
  top: 100px; // where you want it 
  z-index: 1000; // > 10 will probably work
}
```